# Pandas mean across rows and columns in groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'd have a `dataframe` that I'd like to average across rows and columns and grouped by `Person`.

Normally I could do `.mean()` and `.mean(axis=1)`, however, my data has several `NaN` values so this method applies inappropraite weighting to rows with an `NaN` value

```
My code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,np.nan, 'Person A'],
                        [1,2,3, 'Person B'],
                        [2,np.nan,5,'Person B'],
                        [4,5,7, 'Person A']],
                  columns=['A', 'B','C', 'Person'])

df = df.groupby('Person').mean()

print df.mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Person
Person A    4.333333
Person B    2.500000
```

Desired Output:

```
Person
Person A    3.8
Person B    2.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do also:

```
df = df.set_index('Person').stack().groupby(level='Person').mean().to_frame()

print(df)

            0
Person       
Person A  3.8
Person B  2.6
```

`pd.Series.to_frame` is used here because this method return a **Series** object, and you want a **dataframe** back

See that [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by default drop every Nan value `DataFrame.stack(level=-1, dropna=True)[source]`

and **level** takes int, string, or list of these, default last level
Level(s) to stack, can pass level name.

Comment: why does this create a series and not a dataframe?

Comment: @user2242044 according to pandas doc, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html , de method returns a Series. did that affect your result? the method stack()

Comment: no it doesn't but i tried to do a `DataFrame` operation on it after and got an issue, but converted it back a `DataFrame` with  `pd.Series.to_frame(df)`

Comment: @user2242044 I updated the answer, let me know if know you can use the dataframe

Answer (score 4):

```
df.set_index('Person').stack().groupby(level=0).mean().to_frame()
```

Output:

```
Person
Person A    3.8
Person B    2.6
dtype: float64
```

OR

```
df.melt(id_vars='Person').groupby('Person')['value'].mean().to_frame()
```

Output:

```
Person
Person A    3.8
Person B    2.6
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great, but with actual application I hit a memory error. Any idea how do this more efficiently?

Comment: I get the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'`

Comment: Ah. older version of pandas.  In Pandas .20.1 the moved melt to a dataframe method

Comment: pd.melt(df, id_vars='Person').groupby('Person')['value'].mean()  ....give that statement a try

Comment: still get a memory error, `melt` may be better, but neither can handle how much data I need to process. Maybe I can do it in chunks or something.

Comment: @ScottBoston That's so good also, but remember it returns a Serie not DF, plus one btw

Comment: df.groupby('Person')['A','B','C'].apply(lambda x: x.sum(axis=1).sum()/x.count().sum())  How does this do with your memory?

Comment: @DamianLattenero .reset_index or to_frame will get that back to a dataframe.

Comment: @ScottBoston that's totally true! my bad! I didn't see it

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to force those value at -1 to cancel their weight:

```
df.set_index('Person').stack().groupby(level=0).mean()
```

output :

```
Person       
Person A  3.8
Person B  2.6
```

Comment: Thanks good suggestion, but I want them excluded. If they go to 0, it impacts the average.

Comment: @user2242044 Fixed : )

Comment: @Tbaki the previus answer was so much closer, allow me to edit. Plus one for this one.

Comment: @DamianLattenero Thanks ! Didn't know about thoses functionnality, i'll look into it !

Answer (score 1):

A two step process may be more useful if you want to keep the result in the dataframe:

```
df = df.set_index('Person')
df['mean'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Output:

```
          A    B    C  mean
Person                     
Person A  1  2.0  NaN   3.8
Person B  1  2.0  3.0   2.6
Person B  2  NaN  5.0   2.6
Person A  4  5.0  7.0   3.8
```